# how to delete repetitive data records in dataframe by python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

[a dataframe with repetitive data records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52hMv.png)

[Hi dear, I am a rookie while learning python and pandas. I want to delete the repetitive data records in my dataframe with Python and Pandas, containing repetitive data. In the dataframe I have two columns "code" and "number". There are several duplicate rows have the same value for "code", each one corresponding to a number. I only wish to keep one code and save the largest its corresponding number. for example:
"a" has three values: 7, 5, and 4. I hope it only keeps 7 and delete the rest values, same for the other codes. Will anyone help with this please? many thanks]

Comment: drop_duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create dataframe as example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "code": pd.Series(["a", "a", "a", "b", "b"]),
    "number": pd.Series([1,7,3,8,4])
})

df
```

```
code    number
0   a   1
2   a   7
1   a   3
4   b   8
3   b   4
```

Sort dataframe so that code has an order, and then numbers are sorted in increasing manner:

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=["code","number"])

df_sorted
```

```
code    number
0   a   1
2   a   3
1   a   7
4   b   4
3   b   8
```

Drop repeated `codes`, but keep the `code` with largest `number`

```
df_unique = df_sorted.drop_duplicates(subset="code", inplace=False, keep="last")

df_unique
```

```
code    number
1   a   7
3   b   8
```

Comment: Thank you @alejandro very much, that is a perfect answer. Most importantly I have learnt that from you. Many thanks